# How can I use vlookup between 2 different google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a spreadsheet file say **Marks A**, another spreadsheet file **Marks Consolidated**, now I want to consolidate the marks of students entered in **Marks A** file to the same student's marks in file **Marks Consolidated** using a simple vlookup function. (as names will be same in both files).

Is there any way for me to achieve this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

For *range* in the VLOOKUP use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) and authorise the connection.

[image: From IMPORTRANGE help]

Comment: Thank you, I have one small doubt, what do you mean by Authorise the connection?